# sql server: How can I show show category name although there is no record exisits

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to find a way to show category name, age, and total number of 0 even if there is no record exists? Now when I run the below SQL, it returns nothing. Thanks.

```
SELECT 
 'ADMISSION: ' AS CATEGORY_NAME
 ,AGE
 ,COUNT(ID) AS COUNTS
 FROM table
 GROUP BY AGE
```

Comment: If there is no row you can't return it. You need to have a query that returns the row. My guess is that your where predicate is filtering out the row. We can help but you need to provide more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You can use IF ELSE and user IF NOT EXISTS for your SELECT statement and hard code result.

Comment: This kind of operation is often easier to perform in the presentation layer.  How are you displaying the results?  Can the calling app handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Leave out the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT 'ADMISSION: ' AS CATEGORY_NAME,
       COUNT(ID) AS COUNTS
FROM admission;
```

An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` *always* returns one row.  If you have a `GROUP BY`, then such a query will return no rows for an empty table (or if all rows are filtered out).

Also `COUNT()` doesn't return `NULL`.  It returns `0` in this case.

Comment: You can add something like `NULL as age` or `MAX(age) as age` if you like.  Both will assign `NULL` if there are no rows in the table.